# How do I know when the system recognizes a PC card device?

Tags: hardware, notification

I have a bunch of old ethernet PC cards that I am not too sure about (whether they are any good). I want to test them in my laptop to see if they still work (out of curiosity, and because I want to know if Linux supports this hardware).

How do I know when the card has been recognized? Is there a way to get a Notification on card insertion (Notify OSD)? I can take a bit of coding if necessary ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a simple notify-osd utility such as [udev-notify](http://udev-notify.learnfree.eu/) - as the name suggests, it uses `udev` to display a notification when a new device is inserted.

[image]

Alternatively, run a terminal command such as

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

If the kernel does not recognise the device then the output would be "Unclaimed".

Comment: Thanks! I think I have udev-notify already though, so I will need to verify this and also if the pc-cards are being recognized.